# Cascading CSS, bottom-up Cascading

Tags: css

I'm confused with the way CSS is cascading, I thought if you did something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
.small p {
    color: red;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.big p {
    color: green;
    font-size: 50px;
}


.blue p {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="small">
        <p>Small</p>
        <div class="big">
            <p>Big</p>
            <div class="small">
                <div class="blue">
                    <p>Blue inside Small</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is with the "Blue inside Small" , I thought this will be small text as it has an upper class with "small" class. How can I achieve that.

Please don't tell me to change any thing because I'm building a complex template system that you can have containers(divs) inside containers(divs) and I want the bottom-up style to apply !

Comment: If you're going to build "a complex template system" you should probably first have understood how CSS works before starting to write code.

Comment: If you have trouble understanding the Cascade, you should take a look at this: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg

Comment: +1 @Justus. I use that example where I can also :-)

Answer (score 4):

You specified `.big p`'s rule after `.small p`'s rule in your CSS, so the font size will be 50 pixels, not 10, because both selectors are of equal specificity.

CSS cascades its equally-specific selectors top-down (for both CSS rules and the DOM). You can't change that unless you do any of these:

- Make one or more selectors more specific
- Use `!important`
- Modify your HTML

I know you said not to suggest any changes, but I'll do it anyway for the benefit of others — the simplest to make to achieve what you want would be to use the child combinator `>` in the second selector (as suggested by a now-deleted answer):

```
.big > p {
    color: green;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: @wilmoore: Your deleted answer made me realize I was using `>` too many times. I would upvote you but the +10 rep would be lost to the recalc since you deleted it, but thanks :/

Comment: BoltClock , thanks for your answer, I'm developing GWT front framework and I know CSS is not my strong area. Basically you have skinned panels, and I need away to say any text inside that panel has a i.e red text (to opposite of the background), the problem here that panels can have other children panels with different skin and also different foreground color. the problem with .big>p that it will only match the first level !
This should be a simple thing to do. !